# Verilog Arbiter circuit not producing expected output

Tags: verilog, hdl, test-bench

I have an arbiter module set up as follows:

```
// Code your design here
module arbiter#(parameter WIDTH=3)(
    input clk,rst,
    input [WIDTH-1:0] in,
    output reg [WIDTH-1:0] out
    ); 
    parameter IDLE=3'b0,G1=3'b001,G2=3'b010,G3=3'b100;
    reg [WIDTH-1:0] state;    
    wire [WIDTH-1:0] nextState;    

  always@(posedge clk)
     if (rst==1'b1)begin
       state<=3'b000;
       out=3'b000;
     end else begin
      case (state)
    IDLE:if (in==3'b000) begin
            state=IDLE;
            out=IDLE;
        end else if (in == 3'b001)begin
             state=G1;
             out=G1;
        end else if (in == 3'b010 | in==3'b011) begin
            state=G2;
            out=G2;
        end else if (in == 3'b100 | in==3'b101| in==3'b110| in==3'b111) begin
            state=G3;
            out=G3;
        end

   G1:if (in==3'bxx1) begin
            state=G1;
            out=G1;
        end else if (in==3'bxx0)begin
            state=IDLE;
            out=IDLE;
        end

    G2:if (in==3'bx0x) begin
             state=IDLE;
             out=IDLE;
        end else if (in==3'bx1x)begin
              state=G2;
              out=G2;
        end

     G3:if (in==3'b1xx) begin
               state=G3;
               out=G3;
        end else if (in==3'b0xx)begin
                state=IDLE;
                out=IDLE;
         end

endcase

end

endmodule
```

My testbench is as follows:

```
module basic_and_tb();

  reg [2:0] a;
  wire [2:0] out;
  reg clk,rst;

  arbiter uut(.clk(clk),.rst(rst),.in(a),.out(out));

  initial clk=1'b0;

  always #5 begin
    clk=~clk;
  end

  initial begin
    rst=1'b1;
    #10rst=1'b0;
    a=3'b000; $display("%b",out);
    #10 a=3'b010; $display("%b",out);
    #30 a=3'b011; $display("%b",out);
    #10 a=3'b000; $display("%b",out);
    #10 a=3'b100;$display("%b",out);
    #10 a=3'b101;$display("%b",out);
    #20 a=3'b011;$display("%b",out);
    #20 a=3'b010;$display("%b",out);
    #20 a=3'b000;$display("%b",out);
    #10 a=3'b100;$display("%b",out);
    #20 a=3'b000;$display("%b",out);
    #1 $display("%b",out);
    #10 $finish;
  end

endmodule
```

However, the output i get is

```
000
000
010
010
010
010
010
010
010
010
010
010
```

Only one bit of the output can be high at any point in time. When a
request input is asserted while in the idle state, the circuit should grant that request by asserting the corresponding bit of the output. This should remain high until the corresponding input bit is de-asserted, at which point the circuit should move to the idle state. If multiple input bits are
asserted, the highest priority request is granted,with the leftmost bit having the highest priority.However, my output remains at 010 all the way. What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your state machine gets stuck in state `G2` ('b010) because the condition to transition out of that state requires `in` to have x's.  But, you always drive `in` with known values.  Perhaps you meant something like:

```
G2:if (~in[1]) begin
         state=IDLE;
         out=IDLE;
    end else begin
          state=G2;
          out=G2;
    end
```

Similar changes are needed for states G1 and G3.